# How Can I Get MinTTY (Cygwin Terminal) to Open Emacs in a New Window?

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I can't figure out why this isn't easy to find on Google, but after searching for about 10 minutes, I just decided to give up and post here.

The subject basically says it all. I'm running MinTTY as a cygwin terminal on a Windows XP desktop. All I want to do is have emacs open up in a new window rather than inside my terminal. What would be best is a switch for this, so I could toggle it depending on my current needs. This seems like something that would be useful to a lot of people, and I know I've done it before on Linux boxes, so I imagine there must be a way to do this in cygwin too. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start a new mintty, telling it to invoke emacs:

`mintty emacs`

Comment: cool one.. I just added an alias for this.. works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of scenarios that you might clarify:

1. Running the cygwin version of emacs within a standard windows environment will call emacs within the current shell
2. If the Cygwin X-Windows server (i.e., “XWin Server”) has been started and the DISPLAY environment variable has been set in the mintty terminal (e.g., export DISPLAY=":0"), calling emacs will start it in its own window.
3. running the Windows version of emacs within the cygwin terminal should launch the new frame you are seeking.

If you want a separate emacs 'window', you would be best served by installing the Windows native version of emacs (I use the gnu emacs precompiled binaries), and calling it from the cygwin terminal.